# Как правильно добавить background для UIView?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, iphone

Создал вью, накидал объектов и решил добавить фоновый рисунок для вьюхи.
Написал:

```
UIImageView *backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background1.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:backgroundView];
```

В итоге картинка полностью перекрыла все контролы. 
Как мне отправить рисунок на задний план?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вообще любой UIView состоит из CGLayer'ов и у каждого UIVIew имеется backgroundLayer, который на вход принимает UIColor. Но есть вот такая хитрость:

```
 [self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background1.png"]]];
```

Если картинка маленькая она замостит повторениями себя же самой, но это уже другой вопрос.

Answer (score 2):

insertSubview:atIndex: 
А так ты вставляешь поверх всего.
А ещё возникает вопрос, если всё создаётся не динамически, зачем фон делать динамически? 
Динамическое добавление компонентов очень плохо воспринимается другими разработчиками, которые будут потом использовать ваш код, ИМХО.

Comment: Спасибо ребята за помощь, аж 3 варианта добавления бекграунда узнал:)
Теперь другой вопрос: я добавил картинку и она перекрыла статус бар, виден только рисунок батарейки.

Comment: а, ложная тревога. починил

Answer (score 1):

Когда вы добавляете сабвью через [self.view addSubview:] ваша сабвью добавляется на самый верх в иерархии, и соответственно перекрывает те вью, что были добавлены ранее.

Чтобы управлять этим процессом используйте методы

```
[self.view insertSubview:<#(nonnull UIView *)#> aboveSubview:<#(nonnull UIView *)#>]
[self.view insertSubview:<#(nonnull UIView *)#> belowSubview:<#(nonnull UIView *)#>]
```

Таким образом вы можете указать конкретно в какое место иерархии добавить ваше сабвью.

В вашем случае надо сделать так:

```
[self.view insertSubview:backgroundView aboveSubview:self.view]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
self.view.layer.contents = (id)[UIImage imageNamed:@"background1.png"].CGImage;
```